# delayed addclass/remove class function not working

Tags: jquery, addclass

what am I doing wroing here?

```
$(function() {
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass("go").delay(4500).removeClass("go");
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass("go").delay(1500).removeClass("go");
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass("go").delay(500).removeClass("go");
$('ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass("go").delay(4500).removeClass("go");
$('ul li:nth-child(5)').addClass("go").delay(1000).removeClass("go");
});
```

Comment: Little explanation would be handy. I'm guessing you're trying to change the class of a list in a specific order by setting it after a different delay for each item. What bit doesn't work?

Comment: .delay() only delays animations, not functions

Answer (score 42):

Just to add, you can use a [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass("go")
                       .delay(4500)
                       .queue(function() {
                           $(this).removeClass("go");
                           $(this).dequeue();
                       });
```

Comment: Ah I forgot about this +1. Don't forget to `.dequeue()` or `next()` though!

Comment: Its still the same issue - the classes get added to the list items at the same time...then they are removed at different times check: http://jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/8/

Comment: @BizarroZeldman That fiddle seems to demonstrate exactly the behavior that I would expect, given that the delay set for each li has a different value.

Answer (score 17):

`.delay()` is only designed to work with animations. You'll have to resort to using regular setTimeouts for what you're doing:

```
var li = $('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass('go');
setTimeout(function () {
    li.removeClass('go');
}, 4500);
```

To make doing this to every `<li>` a little more pleasant, you can refactor your code like so:

```
$(function () {
    var delays = [4500, 1500, 500, 4500, 1000];
    $('ul li').addClass('go').each(function (i) {
        setTimeout(function (li) {
            li.removeClass('go');
        }, delays[i], $(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm creating an animation where I will have a bunch of list items 'display : none; I then need to add a class to each list item, one at a time, for a pre-determined amount of time, only after the time has passed is the class removed and added to the next list item. At which point the same class will be added to the next list item for a completely different amount of predetermined time.  for a s

Comment: thx, it kinda works... if you look you see that all the classes are applied at the same instant (they all turn blue at exactly the same time) then they all fade away at different intervals. I need the class to be applied to only one list item, once the time has passed, THEN its applied to the next list item