# What is the "right" way to work with addClass/delay/removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple task, when I click on a link, I want to add `bg-success` class into its child, delay 800ms then remove that class.

I can trigger addClass() after click on a link, like this, it works:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.code').addClass('bg-success');
});
```

I can also trigger removeClass after click too, it works (alone) too:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.code').removeClass('test-class');
});
```

I can make it delay, after addClass, let fadeOut, it works:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.code').addClass('bg-success').delay(800).fadeOut(400);
});
```

But when I want to addClass, delay, then removeClass, it does not work, it remains the same and does nothing. I even tried with long time like 8000ms but still can't make it works. If I replaced it with 2 addClass(), it adds 2 classes at the same time, and does not care about delay():

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.code').addClass('bg-success').delay(8000).removeClass('bg-success');
});
```

I have tested with everything I can find on Stackoverflow. The weird part is, it does delay when I work with fadeIn, fadeOut and everything else. The delay() just be ignored when work with addClass/removeClass at the same time.

Anyone have issue like this, please suggest some ideas. Thank you.

---

**Update:**

Read comments and you guys will see the answer is here.

Btw, can anyone with deep knowledge about jQuery explain for me, why they decided to do that? I mean I see it is easy to make this way, addClass then delay then removeClass, what is the real reason makes the jQuery development team decided to make it won't work this way?

I would like to know because if I have the reason, I won't step into the trap like this again.

Comment: .delay() works with the effects queue by default and won't do anything with addClass and removeClass

Comment: You're missing a closing apostrophe on `removeClass('bg-success)`.

Comment: Take a look over here in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such

Comment: @DuncanTidd Thank you but that is just a typo mistake here, not in my code.

Comment: Cool but see @j08691 comment. That's the reason

Comment: @j08691 Oh, I feel like I have just stepped on bear trap. Why would they do that? It's cruel. Btw thank you so much.

Comment: @DannyHoek Thank you, I believe I can follow it to fix this messy.

Comment: This link should help you out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954814/delayed-addclass-remove-class-function-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.delay()` then you need to use **[.queue()](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)** to specify the  queue of functions that will be executed on the element after the delay.

Your code should be:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('span.code').addClass('bg-success').delay(800).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bg-success');
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
});
```

**This is a DEMO snippet:**

```js
    $('a').on('click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('bg-success').delay(800).queue(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('bg-success');
        $(this).dequeue();
      });
    });
```

```css
a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bg-success {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a>A link</a>
```

But you can also simulate this effect with `setTiemout()`:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var myLink = $(this).find('span.code');
  myLink.addClass('bg-success');

  setTimeout(function() {
    myLink.removeClass('bg-success');
  }, 800);
});
```

**`delay()` limitations:**

To get further details why `delay()` is better used with effects only, you can see in the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) that unfortunately, it has some limitations over the native JavaScript `setTimeout` function:

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited. It doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: Thank you, I can get the idea. Btw I updated my question, could you help me little further?

Why they decided to do that? I mean I see it is easy to make this way, addClass then delay then removeClass, what is the real reason makes the jQuery development team decided to make it won't work this way?

I would like to know because if I have the reason, I won't step into the trap like this again.

Comment: @SangĐặng That's because `.delay()` function has some limitations over the native JavaScript `setTimeout` function, take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

(https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

I'd suggest using `setTimeout` like so:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var span = $(this).find('span.code');
  span.addClass('bg-success');

  setTimeout(function() {
    span.removeClass('bg-success');
  }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try with plain old JS with `setTimeout()` function, to wait for certain period of time before doing something else:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var myCode = $(this).find('span.code').addClass('bg-success');
    setTimeout(function(){
       myCode.removeClass('bg-success');
    }, 800);
});
```